# How can I use git to version-control linux folder from windows development IDE remotely?

Tags: git, version-control, zend-studio

Is there any IDE function or any tools( I use Zend Studio ) to allow programmers to code in Windows but the code is saved on a linux server with git? I assume not every programmer needs to have a full stack of testing enviroment on his local PC, right?

(I imagine that the best practice is to be able to create a testing server instance which is virtual machine with full stack testing enviroment set up already. Though I never see one.)

I tried Zend Studio, it seems that I can only clone/create/import a local git repository/branch on my windows machine.

I've heard of using Samba remote file sharing mechanism so to map a hard drive on my windows so to allow me to accomplish this.

I wonder if there is any other way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use git over ssh to access your repositories on linux by cloning them to your Windows computer and pushing back over to your server. You do your work on your IDE that works on Windows on your local clone and push back over to your server for testing.

Another solution would be to mount your server as an SSH drive in Windows. There are several software available for this but https://www.eldos.com/sftp-net-drive/ has worked for me in the past. After mounting you can work on your server files.

One last solution I can think of is using the first solution but adding a `post-receive` hook to check you out a copy you can test on.

Comment: I can push back to a bare repository and that cannot be tested directly. There is some settings to be done to allow me push back to a normal working tree, which is not recommanded. And push is for pure versioning after the testing is done, to me. I'd like to be able to work and test in parallel only not on my local windows machine.